# android circle menu hidden and rotate

Tags: android, menu

i have a circle menu. it works nicely but i have some problems width it. the below list shows what i want:

1. when i tap every where of the screen it will be hidden. how can i prevent it?
2. how can i rotate the menu?

[this is the screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb9YV.jpg)
this is the code i used:

```
    menuExpandItem  = new RadialMenuItem(getString(R.string.about),
            getString(R.string.about));
    menuExpandItem .setDisplayIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menuExpandItem 
            .setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    // Can edit based on preference. Also can add animations
                    // here.
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(mFragmentContainer.getId(),
                                    new RadialMenuAboutFragment()).commit();

                }
            });






  //  pieMenu.setDismissOnOutsideClick(true, menuLayout);
    pieMenu.setAnimationSpeed(0L);
    pieMenu.setSourceLocation(3,200);
    pieMenu.setIconSize(15, 30);
    pieMenu.setTextSize(13);
    pieMenu.setInnerRingRadius(45,90);
    pieMenu.setCenterLocation(550,1500);
    pieMenu.setOutlineColor(Color.BLACK, 225);
    pieMenu.setInnerRingColor(0xfbce25, 180);
    pieMenu.setOuterRingColor(0x0099CC, 180);
    //pieMenu.setHeader("Test Menu", 20);
    pieMenu.setCenterCircle(menuCloseItem);

    pieMenu.addMenuEntry(new ArrayList<RadialMenuItem>() {
        {
            add(menuItem);
            add(menuExpandItem);
            add(menuHome);
        }
    });
```